# How do I add rebound effect to HorizontalScrollView when I press right direction key in android?

Tags: android, animation, scrollview, jelly

I want to add some rebound effect when `HorizontalScrollView` scroll to right edge.
For example, a view like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                     Content                                        |
|                                     Content                                        |
|                                     Content                                        |
|                                     Content                                        |
|                                     Content                                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the normal `HorizontalScrollView`, I press right direction key, this view will have no effect, but I want to this view will rebound like a jelly.

How can I implement this kind animation?

Answer (score 0):

For HorizontalScrollView, if it's width is bigger than it's child view, it won't scroll, so there's no edge effect. You can try this to add rebound effect.

```
public class OverScrollHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
    ...
    public OverScrollHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
    }
    ...
    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY,
                                   int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX,
                                   int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
        maxOverScrollX = 90; // this is the rebound distance, set yours
        return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY,
                maxOverScrollX, maxOverScrollY, isTouchEvent);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your method is useful in `touchEvent`, but not in `keyEvent`. Anyway, Merry Christmas.